# Getting logout everytime in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Getting a problem of logout in codeigniter . Everytime I click button a session is get expired everytime.

I have also set the `$config['sess_expiration'] = 0`.

Kindly help to get out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Check in php.ini your conf. about session.

I found the documentation:

> As a last resort, the Session library will try to fetch PHP’s session
>   related INI settings, as well as legacy CI settings such as
>   ‘sess_expire_on_close’ when any of the above is not configured.
>   However, you should never rely on this behavior as it can cause
>   unexpected results or be changed in the future. Please configure
>   everything properly.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this $config variable and its value from config.php

```
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the ci_session table in your database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_session` (
    session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    ip_address varchar(16) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    user_data text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
    KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```

**Link :** http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 0):

At codeigniter go to applications/config.php and find the below configuration.

```
$config['sess_expiration'] = 32140800; //in seconds
```

Your session not expaire atleast one year